# php mkdir() not working properly

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I can't seem to figure this out.  I realize at this point that this just must be a simple syntax issue that is throwing me off, I'm fairly new to PHP so I am going to thank my noobiness for this one.

I am trying to create subdirectories ($slugTitle) within already existing directories ($w_type), yet the directories are failing to be created.

This is my code:

```
        $path1 = "/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;
        $path2 = "/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle."/images";
        $mode = 0777;

        mkdir($path1);
        mkdir($path2);
```

I've also tried:

```
        $path1 = "/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;
        $path2 = "/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle."/images";
        $mode = 0777;

        mkdir($path1,$mode,TRUE);
        mkdir($path2,$mode,TRUE);
```

and still now luck.  Instead, I get directories that are named " instead of creating a directory within an already existing directory.

Please help! Thank you!

-Joshie

Comment: I've scoured all of the other php mkdir() related posts and none seem to fix my issue.  While my problem is not unique, I need case specific guidance because nothing is working and I've torn almost all of my hair out.

Comment: done any basic debugging, e.g. `var_dump($path1)`? confirmed that the w_type and slugTitle variables contain something that would be valid in a directory name context?

Comment: Do you have permissions to create directories in the root path?

Comment: @MarcB yes the output of `$path1` returns `/existig-directory/new-subdirectory` and `$path2` returns `/existing-directory/new-subdirectory/images`.  Should quotes be added anywhere?  and @Skpd yes, I do have permissions to create directories in the root path.

Comment: no, no quotes, unless you want the quotes to be part of your new directories.

Comment: that's what I thought :/

Comment: the directories are probably being created,just not where you expect them to be.try  $path1 = "./".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;

Comment: @ScroojMcDuck that's what I thought, but they are being created nowhere.

Comment: BTW,which OS are u on?just out of curiosity,did you try the above command.

Comment: @ScroojMcDuck just tried it and that worked! with `$path1 = "./".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;`.  Why did that work?  And Mac OS X 10.7.5 if it's still relevant.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Hey Josh, I tried on my Mac(was on linux before).The "/" represents the root directory and you need root permissions to do any kind of modification there."./" represents the current directory and most of the times you are ok with average user privileges.In short permissions issue and the location of the new directory. BTW,Could you please accept my answer.Might be helpful to someone in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
$path1 = "./".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to add directiries to root directory

try to change

```
$path1 = "/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;
```

to

```
$path1 = "/tmp/".$w_type."/".$slugTitle;
```

or to `dirname (__FILE__) .$w_type."/".$slugTitle;`

Comment: thanks @zool but that didn't work. it still is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a tough time with mkdir() to get it to function in windows using CakePHP.

**This doesn't work properly in windows**

```
mkdir($this -> webroot . "uploads/abc");
```

**Use this instead**

```
mkdir(getCwd() . "/uploads/abc");
```